# Using 'own' in passive voice and causative sentences

Tags: grammaticality

Is it correct to use *own* in causative and passive voice sentences? For example,

> *I had my own house built by a local builder.*
>
> *I didn't have my own eyes tested.*
>
> *His own hair was dyed by a friend.*

Comment: You'd only say *"I had my own house built by a local builder"* if you wanted to differentiate it from other houses you had built (or some similar emphasis). Otherwise, you'd just say *"I had my house built ..."*.

Comment: @Peter that is an excellent point. Can you formalize it as an answer. I was going to answer the same, but you beat me to it.

Comment: Note, this is the **adjective** *own*, not the **verb** *own*, which can be used in the passive and in causative sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct, if you are going for the particular emphasis that the use provides.  All three statements seem emphatic, and may even need an excalamation point at the end. 
The word *own* makes the statements sound either confrontational or defensive.

In all three examples, if I were to read them aloud, I would put stress on the word *own*.

> I had my ***own*** house built by a local builder.

Consider the following dialog:

> > Sally: I don't know if I should go with House Depot or Bill the Builder?
> >
> > Harry: Well, I had my own house built by a local builder.

There the word *own* cannot be ommitted while maintaining the tone. If you just specify emphasis by italicizing *my*, the meaning becomes a bit more ambiguous and changes from confrontational / defensive to possibly haughty.

Consider:

> > Sally: I don't know if I should go with House Depot or Bill the Builder?
> >
> > Harry: Well, I had *my* house built by a local builder.

To me, in the first example, Harry sounds a bit more helpful, whereas in the second, Harry sounds a bit more haughty.

Similar examples can be constructed for other two phrases.